# How to kill the disconnected sessions that runs on the server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an ETL Load. That runs daily but the problem is it is failing most of the time because of disconnected sessions. these sessions are running on the server and consuming lot of memory. hence I need to remove all these sessions manually and again I have to run the entire ETL which consumes lot of time. So I want to do this removing of sessions automatically before ETL Load starts. please help me to get the disconnected sessions and kill them.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you try [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+kill+disconnected+session&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS727US727&oq=sql+server+kill+disconnected+session&aqs=chrome..69i57.7479j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Kill Process using Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808366/sql-server-kill-process-using-stored-procedure)